# Creating and Filling a Matrix

Tags: r

just wondering why this code not working? I am interested in how to use colnames within a if statement.

```
mat <- matrix(, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
row.names(mat) <- c("nc","sc","ny")
col.names(mat) <- c("BMW","Toyota","Honda")

for(row in 1:nrow(mat)) {

    for(col in 1:ncol(mat)) {

        if(colnames(mat1)[1] == "nc"){

            mat[row,col]=0

        }
        else {mat[row,col]=12}
    }

}
```

Thanks a Ton!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your code?

Comment: sorry I did transpose as: mat <- t(mat) but it's still not working

Comment: Also the code works but not how it should, all entries are zero, when only "nc" col entries should be zero; rest should be 12.

Answer (score 1):

The problems in the code are:

- `row.names` should be `colnames`
- `col.names` should be `rownames`
- `mat1` should be `mat`
- `colnames(mat)[1] == "nc"` is always TRUE or always FALSE depending on what `mat` is.  Presumably you want `colnames(mat)[col] == "nc"`

Putting all this together we get:

```
mat <- matrix(, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
rownames(mat) <- c("BMW", "Toyota", "Honda")
colnames(mat) <- c("nc", "sc", "ny")

for(row in 1:nrow(mat)) {
  for(col in 1:ncol(mat)) {
    if(colnames(mat)[col] == "nc") {
      mat[row, col] <- 0
    } else {
      mat[row,col] <- 12
    }
  }
}

mat
##        nc sc ny
## BMW     0 12 12
## Toyota  0 12 12
## Honda   0 12 12
```

Also note that the `if` could be simplified to:

```
mat[row, col] <- if (colnames(mat)[col] == "nc") 0 else 12
```

### Alternatives

**1) Fully vectorized alternative** This could alternately be done in a vectorized, i.e. loop-free, manner like this:

```
mat2 <- matrix(12, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, 
  dimnames = list(c("BMW", "Toyota", "Honda"), c("nc", "sc", "ny")))
mat2[, "nc"] <- 0

identical(mat, mat2)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2) Another fully vectorized alternative**  We can use the following `cbind`.  It only requires one line of code.

```
mat3 <- cbind(nc = c(BMW = 0, Toyota = 0, Honda = 0), sc = 12, ny = 12)

identical(mat, mat3)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Such carelessness and lowsy logic on my part.